# Managing Persistent Files (not database) with Docker

Tags: deployment, docker, web-deployment

What's the best strategy of managing persistent files (not database) such as config file, zip files, images, and so forth?

I tried the following approach:

- Create folder `/var/storage`
- Mount this to my container as `-v /var/storage:/path/to/container/storage/`

However, this does not behave as expected (i.e. only the main folder `storage` is created, and none of the subfolders and files are created. Furthermore, data is not synced. So if I add file to either the container or the host, it does not show up in the other. I'm thinking this is a permission issue.

My other approach (which I have not done yet), would be a container, similar to a database, to allow for a more portable structure.

My question is this: What is the best way to implement this? If I am doing the container way, what is my image then?! There doesn't seem to be anything, so it will just be a completely empty image.

Comment: It's strange that the data is not synced. Permission issues mostly likely will prevent you from make modification, but once made, they should be synced. Are you sure you add the file to the correct location on the host?

Comment: Yes, I want the files to be stored on `/var/storage` on the host. On the container, I don't care where they get mounted, as long as they do!! Is there a way to show the error when I run a `docker run` command so I can see what is happening? Maybe it will yell what the problem is

Comment: Depends on what you run. You can try `docker logs`.

Comment: Are you running boot2docker on OSX by chance? If so, `/path/to/container/storage` must be within your home directory such as `/Users/kousha`.

Comment: My server is on a Linux Debian machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/storage
$ sudo docker run -ti -v /var/storage:/var/inside ubuntu
root@cdc215309a60:/# cat > /var/inside/foo
Hello
^d
root@cdc215309a60:/# exit
exit
$ cat /var/storage/foo
Hello
```

The bit after the colon in `-v` is the location where you want the directory to be mounted inside the container.